# How do I add specific data contained in rows?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm new to R.  Here is my specific question.
Let's say I'm working with the following data set called "data" for this example.  My headers are `state`, `type`, and `value`.

```
structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c(" D", " R"), class = "factor"), value = c(100L, 
200L, 100L, 150L, 100L, 150L)), .Names = c("state", "type", "value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))



  state type value
1    AK    R   100
2    AK    R   200
3    AK    D   100
4    AK    D   150
5    AL    R   100
6    AL    D   150
```

I want to write a function that will add up the values for each type and state.  For example.  For `AK` type `R` the output would be 300.  For `AK` type `D` the output would be 250.  For `AL` type `R` the output would be 100, and for `AL` type `D` the output would be 150.

Comment: Quick tip for you grasshopper: square brackets around R in the search box returns you all questions in the R tag i.e. search for "[R]". Then click the "voted" tab and scroll through the top questions.  Also, over 600 questions contain the word "aggregate" i.e. "[R] aggregate".

Answer (score 7):

Not plyr, but just `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(value~state+type, data=data,FUN=sum)
  state type value
1    AK    D   250
2    AL    D   150
3    AK    R   300
4    AL    R   100
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Saved me loads of time.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [`tapply`](http://www.sigmafield.org/2009/09/20/r-function-of-the-day-tapply)

```
data <- read.csv(header=TRUE,text="state, type, value
AK, R, 100
AK, R, 200
AK, D, 100
AK, D, 150
AL, R, 100
AL, D, 150")

tapply(data$value, list(data$state,data$type), sum)
#     D   R
# AK  250 300
# AL  150 100
```

Answer (score 5):

Although @Matthew Lundberg's answer is the best one here's some alternatives.

If you really want to use plyr you could do:

```
ddply(DF, .(state, type), numcolwise(sum))
  state type value
1    AK    D   250
2    AK    R   300
3    AL    D   150
4    AL    R   100
```

Here's another solution using reshape2 package

```
library(reshape2)
dcast( melt(DF), state + type ~ variable, sum)
Using state, type as id variables
  state type value
1    AK    D   250
2    AK    R   300
3    AL    D   150
4    AL    R   100
```

If you want just a vector then this could be useful:

```
sapply(with(DF, split(value, list(state, type))), sum)
AK.D  AL.D  AK.R  AL.R 
250   150   300   100
```

Answer (score 3):

A plyr solution would be:

```
ddply(data, .(state,type),summarise, total=sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
#   state type total
# 1    AK    D   250
# 2    AK    R   300
# 3    AL    D   150
# 4    AL    R   100
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, there's also the "data.table" package, and `by` in base R. Assuming your dataset is called "myd":

```
by(myd$value, list(myd$state, myd$type), FUN=sum)
# : AK
# :  D
# [1] 250
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : AL
# :  D
# [1] 150
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : AK
# :  R
# [1] 300
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : AL
# :  R
# [1] 100

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(myd)
DT[, sum(value), by = "state,type"]
#    state type  V1
# 1:    AK    R 300
# 2:    AK    D 250
# 3:    AL    R 100
# 4:    AL    D 150
```